Finiteness of the moments of the Malliavin derivative of the stochastic heat equation
I am studying section 2.4.2 from Nualart's book "The Malliavin calculus and related topics" on the stochastic heat equation. I have some questions on the validity of some estimates for the solution and its Malliavin derivative. I imagine that they are well known to the people doing stochastic analysis.
The equation is:
$$ $$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}+b(t, x, u(t, x))+\sigma(t, x, u(t, x)) \frac{\partial^{2} W}{\partial t \partial x} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
$$ x \in [0,1], t\in [0,T] $$
where $b,\sigma$ are infinitely differentiable, bounded, globally Lipschitz, $\sigma$ is bounded from below by a positive constant, $W$ is space-time white noise.
We put the Dirichlet boundary conditions $u(t,0)=u(t,1)=0$ and $u_0$ is continuous and satisfies $u_{0}(0)=u_{0}(1)=0$.
In theorem 2.4.3 in the book it is shown that,
$$\sup_{t\in [0,T],x\in [0,1]} \mathbf{E}( |u(t,x)|^{p} ) < +\infty $$ for all $p \geq 2$.
I am wondering, is it also true that
$$ \mathbf{E} (\sup_{t \in [0,T],x \in [0,1]} u(t,x)^{2})< +\infty  $$  ?
Regarding the Malliavin derivative of the solution, is it true that for any $s \in [0,T],y\in [0,1]$
$$ \mathbf{E} \Big(\int_{0}^{T} \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |D_{y,s} u(t,x)|^{p} dt \Big)< \infty  $$ for some $p>12$ ?
The exponents here can be anything as long as $p>10$.
Finally, it is mentioned around the bottom of page 158 that one can show a Kolmogorov criterion for the process $\{ D_{y,s}u(t,x), s\in [0,t], y\in [0,1] \}$ . It is not obvious to me at all how one would show such a Kolmogorov criterion. I am familiar with how that is done for the solution to the stochastic heat, but I have trouble showing it for the Malliavin derivative because of the extra Green's function term, and the need to have finite moments for the Malliavin derivative.
Any help with these questions would be greatly appreciated!

thanks for the suggestion, I wrote all of them with differentials, hope it looks better now.

For your first question:
Yes, we can use the version of Doob's inequality for the white noise field (appendix  (A.7) of Nualart's related topics book). Let $M(s,t):=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s}f(x,y)W(dx,dy)$
$$E\left[\sup_{s\in [0,S],t\in [0,T]}\left|M(s,t)\right|^{p}  \right]\leq(\frac{p}{p-1})^{2p}E\left[\left|M(S,T)\right|^{p}  \right]\leq (\frac{p}{p-1})^{2p} \sup_{s\in [0,S],t\in [0,T]}E\left[\left|M(s,t)\right|^{p}  \right].$$

For your second question about finite p moments for the integral of Malliavin derivative, you can follow the analogous proof for u(t,x) since we can similarly express $D_{y,s}u_{n+1}(t,x)$ in terms of $D_{y,s}u_{n}(t,x)$.

For your third question about Kolmogorov continuity i.e. Hölder continuity, you can follow the analogous proof in Proposition 2.4.3 of Hölder continuity of $u(t,x)$. Because there they show you how to handle differences of the Green's function. The extra thing you will need are the pth moments for the Malliavin derivative.

I was in the process of writing a long answer, but I thought I should first add those points here because it is taking me some time. If you figure it out, feel free to answer your own question too.

Thank you so much for your answers; they were very helpful! Do you have a reference for the proof of this Kolmogorov estimate? There is an extra term in the Malliavin derivative increments, with the difference of the Green's function not inside an integral, which does not appear for $u(t,x)$ and that I don't know how to bound.  I mean that in $| D_{s,y}u_n(t,x)- D_{s',y'}u_n (t,x)|^{p}$, after bounding $\sigma$, I get $|G_{t-s}(x,y)-G_{t-s'}( x,y')|^{p}$ where  $G_{t-s}(x,y)$ is the Dirichlet kernel. How would I  bound that by $ C(|s-s'|^{\alpha}+|y-y'|^{\beta})$ for $C$ constant?

Also, regarding your answer for the moments of the integrals of the Malliavin derivative, above I have the integral from $0$ to $T$ of the  $sup_{x \in [0,1]}|D_{s,y}u(t,x)|^{p}$, so not exactly its $p$-moment, since there is also a $sup$ inside the integral. Is that also finite?

For the difference |G-G|^p, you can try to use 2.91,2.92 since even for the Malliavian derivative that difference shows up inside integrals.

For the finite moments for Malliavin derivative, you try mimicking the proof for the finiteness of the moments for the heat equation solution in Theorem 2.4.3. Try to obtain the same recursive inequality as he does but for the Malliavin derivatives $Du_{n+1}, Du_{n}$ and then apply Gronwall's lemma. When done, try to include it as an answer below.
